# How to open Open XML with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi i want to get the conection by filterin the atribute Enviroment from my xml
but im gettin some errors can anyone helpme.

here is my code :

```js
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(xml);
var Connections = from conn in xelement.Elements("Conections")
                  where (String)conn.Element("Conection").Attribute("Enviroment") == "Test"
                  select conn;

foreach (XElement conection in Connections)
{
    MessageBox.Show(conection.Element("Conection").Value);
}
```

and Here is my xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Config>
  <General>
    <FormaInicial></FormaInicial>
    <DiasRecordatorioBuro></DiasRecordatorioBuro>
    <EnviarSMSDomiciliacion>rue</EnviarSMSDomiciliacion>
    <SimularDeathLock></SimularDeathLock>
    <IsProductionEnviroment></IsProductionEnviroment>
    <WaitingTimeBetweenExecutions></WaitingTimeBetweenExecutions>
    <NumberTriesBeforeRestartService></NumberTriesBeforeRestartService>
  </General>
  <Conections>
    <Conection Enviroment="Production">
      <Servidor></Servidor>
      <BaseDatos>==</BaseDatos>
      <Usuario></Usuario>
      <Password></Password>
    </Conection>
    <Conection Enviroment="Test">
      <Servidor></Servidor>
      <BaseDatos></BaseDatos>
      <Usuario></Usuario>
      <Password></Password>
    </Conection>
  </Conections>
</Config>
```

Comment: please but non html/javascript/css code in question using `{ }`, also you misspelled `how` in the question title

Comment: What was the error exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing (most likely) is that "Connections" is a collection of "Connection" elements, and when you are trying to filter them by attribute - you will check only the first element. You need to flatten the collection first, using SelectMany:

```
var connections = xelement.Elements("Conections")
            .SelectMany(c => c.Elements("Conection"))
            .Where(c => c.Attribute("Enviroment").Value == "Test");
```

And then in your result you will have a collection of XElements of type "Connection":

```
foreach (var conection in connections)
{
    Console.WriteLine(conection); //a full element with Servidor, BaseDatos, Usuario and Password
    Console.WriteLine(conection.Element("Servidor").Value);    
}
```